# is it possible to use one Svn passwd file for multiple repositories to authenticate users of svn service?

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

well I have several repositories and i want several users to access them using svnserve.exe service.
the problem is that i want to write the user names and passwords only in 1 location.
the Repositories are in the D:\SVN\ path
so lets name them
D:\Svn\Rep1\
D:\Svn\Rep2\ ...

well I tried to modify the svnserve.conf file in each of them to point to a single file like D:\Svn\conf.global\passwd using

password-db=D:\Svn\conf.global\passwd

but it didn't work :(

any ideas? or I need to do it the stupid way and duplicate the passwd file in each repository?

Comment: you should post questions like this on serverfault.com

Comment: but svn is not for system admin.

Comment: it's more for system admins than programming related =)

Comment: It's a debate that almost inevitably occurs on such questions. I settled with the idea that OP's will most likely get more answers here because many developers setup and use versioning systems without really being administrators, it's a developer tool even if a bit server-oriented in the configuration :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this syntax instead:

```
password-db = //./D:/Svn/conf.global/passwd
```

That's the Uniform Naming Convention on Windows to access the local machine (the dot `.` which could be replaced by a machine name) at its root disk `D:`, followed by the path - with slashes here. A little tricky at first glance but does the job.

Comment: thanks, i found that the relative path is working too.
so it can be 
password-db=../../conf.global/passwd

Comment: Yes it can, so long as you keep the password file and the repositories together, should you move them. It could also be less convenient if you organize the structure of your repositories differently (the structure needn't be flat with svnserve, which is a nice advantage over the Apache server) - then the relative path will change depending on how deep the repository is.

Comment: if u have the repositories in non flat structure , u can edit the svnserve.conf to point relativly to the password file for each repository. but the good thing about relative path is that u wont have to edit all ur repositories svnserve.conf files in case you wanted to move the repositories to another location or drive